# How to construct aggregation of $setIsSubset with mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I tried to construct a pipeline with mgo, but I have no idea about how to use **$setIsSubset** operator.

Here is the example from mongodb doc shows the usage of **$setIsSubSet**.
Is there anyone who can give me some tips? :-)

```
<code>

db.experiments.aggregate(
   [
       {$project: {A:1, B:1,AisSubset: {$setIsSubset: ["$A", "$B"]}, _id:0 }}
   ]
)

</code>
```

[mongodb doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset)

Comment: Please update your question with a specific use case that you find not solvable, the desired output, and what you have tried. Otherwise your question is too broad and you will find http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/, as a starting point.

Comment: @BatScream Actually I came from the same link you have just posted,I quoted the sample.What I want to know is how to construct the same pipeline in golang **with mgo**.